# Shorewall deny all assh access except one user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, shorewall

Hi all I have an ubuntu server with shorewall firewall.
I want to deny all ssh access exxcept my user: "alessandro".

How can I write this rule in shorewall?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorewall can not do what you need.
You should put:

```
AllowUsers alessandro
```

into your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: I have already done this. But I don't know if someone entered into my server in some other mode..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mode" but configuring user access restrictions for SSH is done exactly the way I described above. Shorewall has nothing to do with it. Of course there can be other protocols running like FTP, NFS etc. and even though you can totally deny access to them with Shorewall (actually iptables), you still can not put any user restrictions on them at this level.